# Zen Cart template issues

Tags: php, templates, zen-cart

I have been working on a new template for a commerce site running zen cart. This is my first experience making one, and it was going pretty smooth until now. Basically, zen cart's default wording is still in place and I cannot seem to figure out why. For example, on the breadcrumbs, instead of displaying the proper page, I get: `HEADER_TITLE_CATALOG ::  Login` and the title of the page is: `<title>LoginPRIMARY_SECTIONTITLETERTIARY_SECTIONSITE_TAGLINE</title>`

This is happening throughout the site.
I have placed all the necessary header files, and the tpl body page is essentially the same as the default. I am hoping there is a specific solution to this. I can only imagine the page where the php definitions are happening is not being included. Could anyone point me in the correct direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Was missing the Languages folder outside of my template folder. Names game this the same name as my template and copied the files from the default template.